# Initializing Keras Convolution Kernel as a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to initialize the weights for a (5,5) convolutional layer with four channels to be a numpy array. The input to this layer is of shape (128,128,1). In particular, I would like the following:

```
def custom_weights(shape, dtype=None):
    matrix = np.zeros((1,5,5,4))
    matrix[0,2,2,0,0] = 1
    matrix[0,2,1,0,0] = -1

    matrix[0,2,2,0,1] = 1
    matrix[0,3,2,0,1] = -1

    matrix[0,2,2,0,2] = 2
    matrix[0,2,1,0,2] = -1
    matrix[0,2,3,0,2] = -1

    matrix[0,2,2,0,3] = 2
    matrix[0,1,2,0,3] = -1
    matrix[0,3,2,0,3] = -1
    weights = K.variable(matrix)
    return weights

input_shape = (128, 128, 1)
images = Input(input_shape, name='phi_input')

conv1 = Conv2D(4,[5, 5], use_bias = False, kernel_initializer=custom_weights, padding='valid', name='Conv2D_1', strides=1)(images)
```

However, when I try to do this, I get an error of

```
Depth of input (1) is not a multiple of input depth of filter (5) for 'Conv2D_1_19/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,128,128,1], [1,5,5,4].
```

Is my error in the shape of the weight matrix?

Answer (score 1):

There are many inconsistencies (which led to errors) in your code, the error you're getting is not from the given code as it doesn't even index the matrix properly.

```
matrix = np.zeros((1,5,5,4))
matrix[0,2,2,0,0] = 1
```

You are initializing a `numpy` array with 4 dimensions but using 5 indices to change value.

Your dimensions for kernel weights are wrong. Here's the fixed code.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

def custom_weights(shape, dtype=None):
    kernel = np.zeros((5,5,1,4))
    # change value here
    kernel = K.variable(kernel)
    return kernel

input_shape = (128, 128, 1)
images = Input(input_shape, name='phi_input')

conv1 = Conv2D(4,[5, 5], use_bias = False, kernel_initializer=custom_weights, padding='valid', name='Conv2D_1', strides=1)(images)
```